# Display Product Review on Product Page ? - Magento1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, review

I want to know if Is it possible to get product reviews, let's say last 5 to appear on the Product page itself using the default Magento without any paid extension?

Just Below Add Tags options...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

put below code into your `layout/local.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews.list" as="listreviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

and call below line into your `catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('listreviews') ?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.... local.xml was not present in my theme so i created it in layout directory and pasted this code... and also pasted this code in view.phtml but this doesn't seem to be working.. :(

Comment: find updated answer @sehajnarang

Comment: ??? can't understand